# why my *+html CSS is working in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-selectors

I'm using the special selector for IE7 *+html for some adaptations for IE7 :-)

Here is the CSS code wich is shown in chrome... and I don't want to see it except for IE7 indeed :

```
*+html .container, .ui-listview {
position: relative;
top: 41px;
}
```

I use other css with *+html and it only is read by IE7 but this css below

Thanks to help me !

Comment: If you mean that `.ui-listview` is not affected by `*+html`, that's the way it should be. Perhaps you mean `*+html .ui-listview`.

Comment: *+html .container, *+html .container {...} is ok? I want to apply the position and te top to .container AND .ui-listview items !

Comment: it simply works, thanks @AlvaroD

Comment: OK, I'll compose a proper answer

Comment: and I will push "V" with pleasure ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the [grouping operator](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#grouping):

> When several selectors share the same declarations, they may be
>   grouped into a comma-separated list.
>
> In this example, we condense three rules with identical declarations
>   into one. Thus,
>
> ```
> h1 { font-family: sans-serif }
> h2 { font-family: sans-serif }
> h3 { font-family: sans-serif }
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> h1, h2, h3 { font-family: sans-serif }
> ```

So this code:

```
*+html .container, .ui-listview {
    position: relative;
    top: 41px;
}
```

... is equivalent to:

```
*+html .container{
    position: relative;
    top: 41px;
}
.ui-listview {
    position: relative;
    top: 41px;
}
```

This explains that `.ui-listview` is not affected by `*+html`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use these sorts of hacks anymore, to my mind the better solution is conditional comments (ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: To me this is even better: http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/